# Move to Next Row in a SharePoint Document View List

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint

May I know how can I identify the `item` in a SharePoint list view via an `ID`?

Due to some changes, I am unable to use `foreach` as in the situation where a row remains in the list, it resulted in repetitive processing of the same item.

Below is my code snippet and sample scenario.

```
foreach (SPListItem item in unprocessedView)
//list only contains items with "Processed" = false
{
    //if "Type" = "report", 
        //set "Processed" = true. 
        //item does not appear in list anymore.

    //if "Type" = "result"
        //do nothing.
        //item remains in list.
}
```

---

Let's say there are 2 items in `unprocessedView`.

`1.` `result` type.

`2.` `report` type.

---

With the conditions above, item `1.` will not be processed, and remains in the list.

On the loop, `1.` is processed again instead of moving on to item `2.`

May I know how can I workaround this?

Thank you.

Comment: How does it happen that it processes the same item twice ? In your code it looks like it's gonna process them one by one

Comment: I have tested it by updating `1.` after processing, and it moves on to process `2.`. If item `1.` stays and not updated, the loop tries to process `1.` again..

Comment: More likely is that you have duplicates or something. Foreach loop will call GetEnumerator that return `Enumerator` object, it knows how to iterate (move from one object to another) a collection and it's unlikely that it's gonna iterate through the same element twice unless the order in collection has changed. Anyway it's not recommended to use `foreach` loop for *modifying* collections. Instead you could make a copy of it by calling `.ToList()` and iterating through this copy while modifying the real collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the code snippet as below to make it works.

```
foreach (SPListItem item in unprocessedView)
{
    if (item["Type"]!=null&&item["Type"].ToString() == "report")
    {
        item["Processed"] = true;
        item.Update();
    }                         
}
```